# How do I pass a "C" string from a "C" routine to a GO function (and convert it to a GO string?)

Tags: cgo

This must be something really silly and basic, but the cgo docs (and google fu) have left me stranded.  Here's what I am trying to do: I want a GO function to call a "C" function using 'import "C"'.  Said "C" function needs to store the address of a "C" string (malloc or constant - neither has worked for me) into an argument passed to it as *C.char.  The GO function then needs to convert this to a GO string.  It actually *does* work, except I get this:

panic: runtime error: cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer

If I run with GODEBUG=cgocheck=0, it all works fine.  If I leave as default:

```
strptr = 4e1cbf ('this is a C string!')
main: yylex returned token 1
yylval.tstrptr 4e1cbf
stringval token "this is a C string!"

The problematic line seems to be:

   yylval.stringval = C.GoString(yylval.tstrptr)
```

What little I can find about C.GoString, it left me with the impression that it allocates a GO string, and fills it in from the "C" string provided, but that seems to not be the case, or why am I getting a complaint about 'Go pointer to Go pointer'?  I've tried a number of other approaches, like having the "C" function malloc the buffer and the GO function do C.free() on it.  Nothing has worked (where worked == avoiding this runtime panic).

The GO source:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "unsafe"
)

// #include <stdio.h>
// int yylex (void * foo, void *tp);
import "C"

type foo_t struct {
        i int32
        s string
}

var foo foo_t

func main() {

        var retval int
        var s string
        var tp *C.char

        for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
                retval = int(C.yylex(unsafe.Pointer(&foo), unsafe.Pointer(&tp)))

                fmt.Printf("main: yylex returned %d\n", retval)

                fmt.Printf("tp = %x\n", tp)

                if retval == 0 {
                        s = C.GoString(tp)
                        fmt.Printf("foo.i = %d s = %q\n", foo.i, s)
                } else {
                        foo.s = C.GoString(tp)
                        fmt.Printf("foo.i = %d foo.s = %q\n", foo.i, foo.s)
                }
        }
}

The "C" source

#include <stdio.h>

int yylex (int * foo, char ** tp)
{
  static num;

  *foo = 666;
  *tp = "this is a C string!";

  printf ("strptr = %x ('%s')\n", *tp, *tp);

  return (num++);
}
```

What's interesting is that if the GO func stores into foo.s first, the 2nd call to yylex bombs with the panic.  If I do s and then foo.s (depending on whether I check retval as 0 or non-zero), it doesn't fail, but I'm guessing that is because the GO function exits right away and there are no subsequent calls to yylex.

Comment: I tried an experiment: have the "C" function return the "C" char * pointer, and pass that directly to C.GoString(), and no more panic.  I wonder if there's a bug in cgo?

Comment: Speculation: if I pass no pointers to the "C" routine, and have it pass a pointer back, which is never stored in any GO variable, that seems to avoid the issue.  Hmmm...